# Gradle pass SystemProperties to JUnit test

Tags: gradle, groovy, junit, properties

How can I use `gradle parameters` in my `JUnit` test cases?

I tried this:

build.bradle:

```
test {
    systemProperty 'brand', System.properties['brand'] ? project.brand : 'abc'
}
```

In my test I displayd all properties with:

```
System.properties.each { k,v->
    log.info("$k = $v")
}
```

With that code I get a lot of properties, except for `brand`.

Is there another way to get brand into my test?

// I don't know if it's important but I'm using Gebish or rather Selenium for my tests too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why using `systemProperty` does not work in the `test` configuration, but for a workaround you can set the `systemProperties` variable like:

```
test {
    System.properties.'brand' = System.properties['brand'] ? project.brand : 'abc'
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

Or if you don't want to modify `System.properties` you can set `systemProperties` like

```
test {
    systemProperties = System.properties + ['brand1': System.properties['brand'] ? project.brand : 'abc']
```

}

Comment: jUnit uses for each test a new JVM. Gebish somehow too. Your idea is not working for. But I got a ugly workaround. In my build.gradle I have `systemProperty "brand", project.hasProperty("brand") ? project.brand : "abc"` in the test task. In my GebConfig.groovy I have `brand = System.getProperty("brand") ? System.getProperty("brand") : "abc"` (here abc again, because Intellij does not run the task properly) and in my test itself I have `def brand = browser.config.getRawConfig().getProperty("brand").toString()`. Took me now over 4 hours to find that way

Comment: the systemProperties should set the System.properties in the new JVM In the Geb and Junit tests I'm doing the obove. are you sure you set the systemProperties variable?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I just tried it again and System.properties (in a test) had no brand key.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is now:

build.gradle (in the test task):

```
systemProperty "brand", project.hasProperty("brand") ? project.brand : "abc"
```

GebConfig.groovy:

```
brand = System.getProperty("brand") ? System.getProperty("brand") : "abc"
```

here abc again, because IntelliJ does not run the task properly, but it does through the command line

in the test itself:

```
def brand = browser.config.getRawConfig().getProperty("brand").toString(‌​)
```